# Youtube iframe - Tap to toggle play / pause not working on tablets

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

To reproduce:

- Watch an YouTube video embedded with the iframe API on a tablet
- Tap on the video
- Instead of toggling play / pause, the tap triggers that behavior:

[image: Tapping shows the YouTube contextual menu instead of toggling Play/Pause]

Is this normal at all?

Comment: Indeed seems to be a bug. Link to the corresponding thread in the YouTube help forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/jd7hK8TOxsY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed by Google.